# Extracting the imaginary part of data from fft in R

Tags: r, filtering

I need to filter the imaginary part of a forward fourier transform.

I've been trying to use filter.complex (but R keeps saying function filter.complex does not exist)

I've used only filter, and I get the following warning message-

```
imaginary parts discarded in coercion
```

Please tell me if I'm missing something

This is an example:

```
    x = fft(rec-mean(rec))/sqrt(length(rec))
    y = fft(soi-mean(soi))/sqrt(length(soi))
    fyx = filter.complex(y * Conj(x), rep(1, 15), sides = 2, circular = TRUE)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly. Can you please add a reproducible example? Or does something like `x <- 1:4; filter(Im(fft(x)), 1)` (i.e., using `Im` to extract the imaginary part) work for you?

Comment: I have added an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried unsuccessfully to find a `filter.complex` function (and I'm reasonably good art searching such things out.) I don't think it exists. I think you may have gotten a hold of some old S code that was set up for dispatching to the complex class. If I trim the command to just:

```
fyx = filter(y * Conj(x), rep(1, 15), sides = 2, circular = TRUE)
```

...., I get the identical message. It's apparently from the deeper code called at the C-level since that message is not visible in the R-code that appears when you just type "filter" at the command line. Searching with Google for the error message shows it's probably coming from: http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/coerce.c .

It is just a warning, and not necessarily evidence of wrong-doing on your part.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong. The function 'filter.complex' was not defined in any package.
So, I defined it as follows-

```
filter.complex=function(x,...){complex(real=filter(Re(x),...), imag=filter(Im(x),...))}
```

This filtered the imaginary part that I needed.